# Trying to find file location of Mac Mail Smartboxes so that I can run automatic email archiver

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, storage, archive

I'm currently working on a MacBook late 2008 with OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.
I use Mac Mail for my email.

I have created smart mailboxes to collect together emails that relate to a project number.
When the project is complete I want to be able to archive the emails into PDFs and store them on Dropbox.

I have purchased Email Archiver for the purpose.
Email Archiver needs the source folder destination and I can't find the smartbox location. I have looked in Library/Mail/V2/MailData and can see the SmartMailBoxes.plist but I can't see folders relating to specific smartmailboxes.

Anyone got any suggestions about how I can achieve this?
Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 2):

The smart mailboxes aren't real mailboxes—they're just filters stored in Mail preferences. You can't find the location of the smart mailbox because it's not actually stored separately on disk.

Answer (score -1):

el capitan = SyncedSmartMailboxes.plist